# Is it possible to control the Laptop Camera to flicker? On and Off?

Tags: python, security, camera, led, flashlight

i'm working on a project atm , about air-gap communication 
and i was wondering if the laptop camera led can be controlled with out actually turning the camera software on and off ? 
i'm looking forward to control the led to transmit a binary signal , 
so turning the camera it self on and off , wouldn't be so good in terms of frequencies .

Comment: It surely depends on the level of access you have, and the actual camera model. With full access (controlling / being able to modify the driver, be it any OS) it may be possible for some cameras and not for others.